# Grails 4: How to test code that depend on Converters (like "as JSON")

Tags: testing, grails

How to write a test (functional, unit, integration) to test a class that contains a Grails converter(s)? At the minimum I should be able to write a working integration test.

Example: The following line works fine outside of the test scope, but fails in both unit-tests and integration tests:

```
def json= "{}" as JSON
```

with `GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'grails.converters.JSON'`. The expected outcome is that a `JSON` type is returned.

There seems to be the same problem with earlier versions in [GRAILS-4715](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/3660), however its been closed so I assume it was fixed. In Grails 3.X this issue could be circumvented like this [How do I unit test a Grails service that uses a converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785708/how-do-i-unit-test-a-grails-service-that-uses-a-converter/15485593#15485593). However, none of the presented workarounds seem to work in Grails 4.X. I tried manually enabling and registering the converters in the same manner it was done in Grails 3 with `@TestMixin`, but this was a dead end for me.

Using Grails version 4.0.3.

I also opened I ticket for this towards the Grails project https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11521 hoping for a long term solution to the problem or at least some documentation on how to test this common use case of Grails converters.

Comment: The code above by default does not work in either 3.3.x or 4.0.x. I get the same exception in 3.3.9 with that. Converters usually convert domain objects to a json string, not the other way around (though I suppose you could write a custom converter to do that.) - There seems to be more going on in your app we'd need to know to help you more.

Comment: @erichelgeson Seems like I oversimplified the example. I will update tomorrow.